# How to Enable and Disable Table View cell one by one in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am new to iOS and I am facing a problem regarding enabling and disabling UITableView cells. I want to enable the first cell and disable the other cells. When I click on the first cell, the second cell gets enabled. Can I do this?

I am using this code:

```
cell.userInteractionEnabled = false;
```

But it disables all the cells in the table view. Can I enable cells one by one?

I am not tapping the cell, but a button in the cell, which runs this method:

```
- (void)rateView:(RateView *)rateView ratingDidChange:(int)rating
{
    NSLog(@"Rating =%d",rating);

    rateviewintvalue=rating;

    KPINextTableview *cell = rateView.superview.superview;
    // NSLog(@"%@",cell.actuallbl.text);

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [kpitable indexPathForCell:cell];
    CurrentIndexPath=indexPath.row;
    String2=cell.Kpiidlbl.text;

    self.currentlyEnabledCellIndex = self.currentlyEnabledCellIndex + 1;

    NSLog(@"String 2 =%@",String2);

    NSString *RateString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",rating];
    ratingcoredata=RateString;
    kpiidcoredata=String2;
    commentString=@"";

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Get_KpiPoints_User"];
    self.devices = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSError *error;

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"AuditPost" inManagedObjectContext:context]];

    //  NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
        NSLog(@"Result =%@",results);

    CompareArray=[devices valueForKey:@"kpiid"];


    BOOL contains = [CompareArray containsObject:kpiidcoredata];
    if(contains == NO)
    {
        if (self.device) {
            // Update existing device
            [self.device setValue:ratingcoredata forKey:@"rating"];
            [self.device setValue:kpiidcoredata forKey:@"kpiid"];
            [self.device setValue:commentString forKey:@"kpicomment"];

        } else {
        // Create a new device
        NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Get_KpiPoints_User" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    //  NSLog(@"context",newDevice);
        [newDevice setValue:ratingcoredata forKey:@"rating"];
        [newDevice setValue:kpiidcoredata forKey:@"kpiid"];
        [newDevice setValue:commentString forKey:@"kpicomment"];

        //NSError *error = nil;
        // Save the object to persistent store
            if (![context save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSError *error = nil;
        // Save the object to persistent store
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
        }

        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Get_KpiPoints_User" inManagedObjectContext:context]];

        //  NSError *error = nil;
        NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
        NSManagedObject* favoritsGrabbed = [results objectAtIndex:CurrentIndexPath];
        [favoritsGrabbed setValue:ratingcoredata forKey:@"rating"];
        // Save the object to persistent store
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }
    if(rating<=3)
    {
        UIAlertView *testAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning!"
                                                            message:@"Please Enter Reason"
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                  otherButtonTitles:@"Done", nil];
        textView1 = [UITextView new];
        lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0,90.0, 34.0)];


        [lbl setText:@"Enter Remark"];
        [lbl setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
        [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [lbl setTextColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
        textView1.delegate = self;

        [textView1 addSubview:lbl];

        [testAlert setValue: textView1 forKey:@"accessoryView"];

        [testAlert show];
    }

    DataModel *model = [arrData objectAtIndex:rateView.tag];
    model.RateViewValue = RateString;

    //example reload table
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [kpitable reloadData];
    });

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, you want only the first cell to be enabled. Then when that's tapped, you want only the second cell to be enabled, and so on?

Comment: @mattsson Yes I want exactly like this.

Comment: @Muju are you struggeling with the same project?

Comment: @Gulliva Yes.That is same project but different issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UITableView Delegate to disable touch events for single cells in your TableView.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614988-tableview

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row < 10) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

The "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" delegate method will not be called for cells which doesnt highlight.

Answer (score 0):

I would store an `NSInteger` property with the currently enabled cell index, e.g.:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger currentlyEnabledCellIndex;
```

Assign it to 0.

Then implement this `UITableViewDelegate` method to control selection:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (self.currentlyEnabledCellIndex == indexPath.row) {
        return indexPath;
    }
    else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

When the right cell is selected, update `currentlyEnabledCellIndex`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.currentlyEnabledCellIndex = self.currentlyEnabledCellIndex + 1;
}
```

Make sure to set it back to 0 when you reach the last cell.

Comment: No It selecting all the value in table view cell.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @mattson I am taking value on button click not in didselectrowatindexpath.

Comment: What do you mean? Which value are you taking?

Comment: I am using custom table view and used rate view.I am getting value on rate view delegate - (void)rateView:(RateView *)rateView ratingDidChange:(int)rating

Comment: What does that have to do with my answer?

Comment: I understand now. You should then update `currentlyEnabledCellIndex` in `ratingDidChange`, but it looks like you're doing that. Does it not work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133010/discussion-between-mattsson-and-muju).

Comment: Not work. In viewdidload I setting it as  self.currentlyEnabledCellIndex=0;
.

Comment: Is `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` being called? Do you have the UITableView's delegate set?

Comment: @mettsson Not  call. Yes I set TableView delegate.

Comment: Have you set the UITableView's delegate?

Comment: tableview.delegate=self;